# How to make an async POST request with a big response that fires DownloadProgressChanged?

Tags: c#, download, mono, webclient

I am using the `WebClient` class to interact with a server that has only one endpoint URL, and instead accepts paths as POSTed values, in JSON (not that it matters).

Using `UploadStringTaskAsync`, I can asynchronously make such requests and read their responses just fine. However, now I'm faced with the requisite of downloading a file from that server. It is a quite big file (up to hundreds of megabytes), so there should be a progress indication on my program's interface. However `UploadStringTaskAsync` does not fire the `DownloadProgressChanged` event, and so, I cannot access the amount of bytes that have been downloaded.

How can I receive this file, and be able to be notified of progress? Or is there any other class I can use that allows me to do POST requests with huge responses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind is that you open the download as a stream, write your own copy loop and do the progress reporting from there. This is guaranteed to work.

WebClient seems to be inadequate for that. WebClient wraps HttpWebRequest so just use that. Or use the more modern HttpClient. Those two are guaranteed to support obtaining a stream (that actually streams).

Comment: But how can I open the download stream after sending the POST data? As far as I understand, the `OpenWrite` method returns a write-only stream.

Comment: WebClient seems to be inadequate for that. WebClient wraps HttpWebRequest so just use that. Or use the more modern HttpClient. Those two are guaranteed to support obtaining a stream (that actually streams).

Comment: What do you think of just using the synchronous version? Seems like a simple fix.

Comment: `HttpWebRequest` is marked as obsolete, `HttpClient` seems like a good option, by reading as a stream. How would the synchronous version of `UploadString` help? It doesn't return a stream, and the progress event is explicitly only called on asynchronous operations. And the reason I'm using async is to not hang the UI during those downloads, not for scalability.

Comment: Sorry if I sounded defensive, I did not mean to while writing the comment.

Comment: Your comment is totally fine. OK, you can unhang the UI by doing await Task.Run(...). That always works. HttpWebRequest obsolete?! That's madness. That API is totally OK and will be there for a decade to come. Maybe they marked it obsolete to push async in the context of WP. They do a lot in order to push async in the last few years. Don't necessarily listen to the propaganda.; Regarding no stream with WebClient, I'm not too familiar with that API. If you don't find a suitable method in the list of methods jettison it and use e.g. HttpClient.

Comment: `How would the synchronous version of UploadString help?` I understand you could use the progress event in that case. Maybe I misunderstood. I have never used that event before.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up settling with HttpClient and manually reading the response stream. If you would be so kind to edit the answer with that suggestion, I'll accept it. As for the WebClient progress event, citing the documentation: _Occurs when an **asynchronous** download operation successfully transfers some or all of the data._